# Spring Boot trusted packages for rabbitmq

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

We're building a Spring Boot application (2.0.4-RELEASE) that receives messages via RabbitMQ. Hence the `application.properties` contains the rabbit related config:

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=****
spring.rabbitmq.username=****
spring.rabbitmq.password=****
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.concurrency=2
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=5
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.enabled=true
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.retry.max-attempts=5
```

Configuration:

```
@Bean
public TopicExchange fileUpdate() {
    return new TopicExchange("my.fancy.exchange", true, false);
}

@Bean
public Queue fileUpload() {
    return new Queue("myFancyQueue", true);
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingUpload(Queue queue, TopicExchange eventExchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(eventExchange).with("");
}
```

Message Consumer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "myFancyQueue")
public void receive(Object message) {
    ...
}
```

When receiving a message of a specific type (e.g. `__TypeId__: my.fancy.package.Clazz`) the following error is thrown:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'my.fancy.package.Clazz' is not
>   in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this
>   class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the
>   serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable
>   trust all (*).

From what I've discovered so far activeMQ provides a configuration option for that through the `application.properties` as

```
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=
```

or

```
spring.activemq.packages.trusted=
```

but I can't find any similar option that would work for rabbitMQ. So far I've been using a workaround that solves my problem but of course it would be great to have an option like that in the configuration file.

My solution so far:

Adding to the configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(new ObjectMapper());
    jsonMessageConverter.setClassMapper(new ImporterClassMapper(FileUploadMessage.class));        
    return jsonMessageConverter;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
    return template;
}
```

And changing the message consumer to

```
@Resource(name = "jsonMessageConverter")
private MessageConverter messageConverter;

@RabbitListener(queues = "${uploaded.files.queue}")
public void receive(Message message) {
    FileUploadMessage uploadMessage = (FileUploadMessage) messageConverter.fromMessage(message);
    ...
}
```

Plus adding a class mapper that allows unkown types to be imported and sets a default type to which messages should be cast to on import:

```
public class ImporterClassMapper implements ClassMapper, InitializingBean {

    private volatile Class<?> defaultType;

    public ImporterClassMapper(Class<?> defaultType) {
        this.defaultType = defaultType;
    }    

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void fromClass(Class<?> clazz, MessageProperties properties) {
        // avoid setting __TypeId__ header so consumers from other modules can implement their own DTOs
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> toClass(MessageProperties properties) {
        return this.defaultType;
    }

    public void setClass(Class<?> type) {
        this.defaultType = type;
    }
}
```

Any advise on how to improve this solution?

Comment: I think using JSON to send/receive arbitrary types is the recommended approach...

Comment: Yes, of course the types are transfered in JSON. Yet a __TypeId__ is provided with them. The DefaultClassMapper will then always try to cast the JSON into the type and throw an exception if the consumer doesn't know the type

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the same error by setting trusted packages on the Spring AMQP ClassMapper being used.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfig {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory rabbitListenerContainerFactory(SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        factory.setMessageConverter(jsonToMapMessageConverter(objectMapper));
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonToMapMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter = new ImplicitJsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);
        DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        classMapper.setTrustedPackages("*");
        classMapper.setDefaultType(Map.class);
        messageConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);
        return messageConverter;
    }

    public static class ImplicitJsonMessageConverter extends Jackson2JsonMessageConverter {    
        public ImplicitJsonMessageConverter(ObjectMapper jsonObjectMapper) {
            super(jsonObjectMapper, "*");
        }    
        @Override
        public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws MessageConversionException {
            message.getMessageProperties().setContentType("application/json");
            return super.fromMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: although it took me a while - yes, that's a better approach. keeps me from implementing custom class mappers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

As `CVE-2023-34050` and [Spring AMQP DOC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#json-message-converter)
There's an alternative way:

set

OS environment variable `SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL` to `true`.

or `VM options` to `-Dspring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all=true`

It worked, But not good way.